Induced map on Lie algebra of product of Lie group morphisms
I am working with Lie groups and Lie algebras and have some trouble with proving something that I think is right.
Let $G$ be a (simply connected) Lie group. Let $\mathfrak g = T_e G$ be its associated Lie algebra.
Assume that we have two Lie group endomorphisms $\theta: G\to G$ and $\zeta: G\to G$ such that $\text{Im} \zeta \leq Z(G)$. Then the product $\theta\cdot \zeta$ is a well-defined Lie group morphism. Now I want to get the following result:
$$(\theta\cdot\zeta)^\ast = \theta^\ast+\zeta^\ast.$$
Here the $\ast$ in the superscript denotes the induced Lie algebra morphisms on $\mathfrak g$ (so the derivatives).
I suspect that this is true, because if I use the identity $\exp\circ\varphi^\ast = \varphi\circ\exp$ and the Campbell-Baker-Hausdorff formula for the exponential map, then the fact that $\zeta$ (and hence $\zeta^\ast$) has image lying in the center yields that
$$\exp\circ(\theta\cdot\zeta)^\ast = \exp\circ(\theta^\ast+\zeta^\ast).$$ However, the exponential map need not be injective and hence I don't know how to solve it.
Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks in advance!

Believe it or not, we don’t need any fancy machinery to prove this. It’s just the chain rule.
Let $\mu:G\times G\to G$ denote the group operation on $G$. Then, $$\theta\cdot\zeta=\mu(\theta,\zeta):G\to G\times G\to G\times G\to G,$$ sending $g\mapsto (g,g)\mapsto (\theta(g),\zeta(g))\mapsto\mu(\theta(g),\zeta(g))$, and we can apply the chain rule (using your notation): $$X\mapsto (X,X)\mapsto (\theta^*(X),\zeta^*(X))\mapsto\mu^*(\theta^*(X),\zeta^*(X)),$$ and $$\mu^*(\theta^*(X),\zeta^*(X))=l_{\theta(e)}^*\zeta^*(X)+r_{\zeta(e)}^*\theta^*(X)=\theta^*(X)+\zeta^*(X),$$ where $l_g$ and $r_g$ are left and right translation by $g$, respectively.

Hi @user815293, thank you for your answer! I was able to follow your reasoning. When I write everything out, I however seem to never use the assumption that the image of  $\zeta$ is contained in the center of $G$. Is this possible? Of course this assumption is important as a product of two group morphisms is not necessarily a group morphism, so $\zeta$ being central fixes that. Is it right when I say that it is never used elsewhere in the proof here?

Correct. If you took two smooth maps from $G$ to itself that happened to fix the identity element, then the same argument above works. Their product wouldn’t necessarily be a homomorphism, but the chain rule still goes through.
